How to read the value of CDPJSHandle {}?
I am just trying to scrap something from a website.
I am running into a problem when trying to access the value of a property that is on an element. The value returns CDPJSHandle {} instead of the object that I expect.
import * as puppeteer from "puppeteer";

const main = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://google.com');

  const element = await page.$('canvas');
  const properties = await element.getProperties();
  const [firstKey]  = await properties.keys();
  const propertyValue = await element.getProperty(firstKey);

  console.log({
    element,        // CDPElementHandle { handle: CDPJSHandle {} },
    properties,     // Map(1) { 'jQuery3700346878389459100542' => CDPJSHandle {} },
    firstKey,       // 'jQuery3700346878389459100542',
    propertyValue,  // CDPJSHandle {}
  });

  await browser.close();
}

main();

This jQuery3700346878389459100542 is a custom property attached to this html element. I can access the property via the browser with document.querySelector('canvas').jQuery370058052487285485872; which returns the object that I expect.
I know that a similar question has been asked here, which will work if I'm referencing a native HTML element property. However my scenario differs as I'm looking for a custom property.
const evaluatedValue = await element?.evaluate((el, firstKey) => el[firstKey], firstKey);
const evaluatedTextValue = await element.evaluate(el => el.id);

console.log({
  evaluatedValue, // undefined
  evaluatedTextValue, // '\n                        '
});

How can I access this property correctly?

What's firstKey in your bottom example? It should be const firstKey = "jQuery370058052487285485872". Please share a [mcve]. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I wouldn't select by "first" key"--keys are unordered. evaluate is the proper tool for extracting data from DOM elements, though, avoid ElementHandles.

Hey @ggorlen. I've updated the description of the questions with a working example targeting a sample page. The issue should be reproducible. The Map only ever contains one record, so order is not important. To you suggestion of using evaluate this returns undefined e.g. const elementProperty = await document.querySelector('canvas')?.jQuery3700346878389459100542;

Thanks for the update. That's not what I suggested, but what data are you trying to get exactly?

I'm not sure what data you're ultimately trying to get, so this might be an XY problem because there's likely a more straightforward way to solve your real problem, but here's how you can extract some of the data from that dynamic circular object:
import puppeteer from "puppeteer"; // ^22.7.1

const url = "<Your URL>";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  await page.waitForFunction(`
    Object.keys(
      document.querySelector("canvas")
    ).some(k => k.startsWith("jQuery"))
  `);
  const data = await page.$eval("canvas", el => {
    const {isEventSeries, needsDateAndTime, src} =
      Object.entries(el).find(([k, v]) =>
        k.startsWith("jQuery")
      )[1];
    return {isEventSeries, needsDateAndTime, src};
  });
  console.log(data);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

Output:
{
  isEventSeries: 'False',
  needsDateAndTime: 'False',
  src: 'Veranstaltungen2/534be454-f064-42f4-a434-8530d8ad4a48'
}

Avoid element handles whenever possible, they're nasty to work with. Just extract the data with $eval, $$eval, or evaluate.
page.$() doesn't auto wait, which is necessary here since the property is added to the canvas dynamically, so that's mostly off the table, at least if you're going to use the fastest {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"} predicate on the goto, which you should (linked blog post is mine).
